# Why this edit was approved?

Tags: discussion, edits

Take a look at this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31669368/revisions

The content is valid but it is not really fair.

> Provided brief description and added alternate method do remove unused resources

I just want to know if this a legal way to edit the answer, since we have a lot of deprecated answers on SO.

Comment: The only reviewer [actually rejected it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13302828), but the author of the post (who has a binding vote) approved it and edited it further, so it was accepted. That's why the Community user is shown as the user that approved the edit.